# How to add compressor curve in Aspen HYSYS for a centrifugal compressor with IGV and only one efficiecy 65% is given in data sheet at 400rpm

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering

I am trying to check the adequacy of existing centrifugal compressors in a gas train.

The adequacy check is required due to a new tie-in in an existing gas train inlet, from a new source of "flare gas recovery liquid ring compressor".

The given data from the client has the compressor data sheet with polymorphic efficiency 65% and ram 400 in the data sheet.

The compressor Curve has IGV (inlet guide vanes) and no information about efficiency change with different IGV values.

How can such curve data be added in Aspen HYSYS?

Comment: Surely you should be asking the manufacturer, not us?